# Cassandra NOT EQUAL Operator

Tags: mapreduce, cassandra, cql3

Question to all Cassandra experts out there.

I have a column family with about a million records.

I would like to query these records in such a way that I should be able to perform a `Not-Equal-To` kind of operation.

I Googled on this and it seems I have to use some sort of `Map-Reduce`.

Can somebody tell me what are the options available in this regard.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can suggest a few approaches.

1) If you have a limited number of values that you would like to test for not-equality, consider modeling those as a `boolean` columns (i.e.: column `isEqualToUnitedStates` with true or false).

2) Otherwise, consider emulating the unsupported query `!= X` by combining results of two separate queries, `< X` and `> X` on the client-side.

3) If your schema cannot support either type of query above, you may have to resort to writing custom routines that will do client-side filtering and construct the not-equal set dynamically.  This will work if you can first narrow down your search space to manageable proportions, such that it's relatively cheap to run the query without the not-equal.

So let's say you're interested in all purchases of a particular customer of every product type except Widget.  An ideal query could look something like `SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE customer = 'Bob' AND item != 'Widget';`  Now of course, you cannot run this, but in this case you should be able to run `SELECT * FROM purchases WHERE customer = 'Bob'` without wasting too many resources and filter `item != 'Widget'` in the client application.

4) Finally, if there is no way to restrict the data in a meaningful way before doing the scan (querying without the equality check would returning too many rows to handle comfortably), you may have to resort to MapReduce.  This means running a distributed job that would scan all rows in the table across the cluster.  Such jobs will obviously run a lot slower than native queries, and are quite complex to set up.  If you want to go this way, please look into *Cassandra Hadoop integration*.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use not-equals operator on a specific partition key and get all other data from table then you can use a combination of range queries and  TOKEN function from CQL to achieve this

For example, if you want to fetch all rows except the ones having partition key as 'abc' then you execute below 2 queries

```
select <column1>,<column2> from <keyspace1>.<table1> where TOKEN(<partition_key_column_name>) < TOKEN('abc');
select <column1>,<column2> from <keyspace1>.<table1> where TOKEN(<partition_key_column_name>) > TOKEN('abc');
```

But, beware that result is going to be huge (depending on size of table and fields you need). So you might want to use this in conjunction with dsbulk kind of utility. Also note that there is no guarantee of ordering in your result. This is just a kind of data dump which will most probably be useful for some kind of one-time data migration like scenarios.